# Vue js computed property not updating gradient text

Tags: css, vue.js

My computed property sometimes updates sometimes doesn't, the thing is it updates perfectly when I inspect the element. The problem is in the gradient font class which the element has, once I remove it the property updates correctly.

So once this class is removed the thing works, ofc I need both the gradient and the property to work. I'm not sure how this works, color transparent and background clip, but it messes up the vue js.

```
.gradText {
    background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(to right, #FFB42A, #FA7001) !important;
    background-image: linear-gradient(to right, #FFB42A, #FA7001) !important;
    color: transparent !important;
    background-clip: text !important;
    -webkit-background-clip: text !important;
}
```

Comment: Why are you using `!important` on every line? If it's like this here are you using that elsewhere? That forces the attribute to not be overridden due to normal specificity rules and can cause lots of issues like what you're experiencing.

Comment: It would also help if you'd provide more context or a repeatable example.